# How to allow nbd devices to submit io requests simultaneously more than physical cpu cores?

Tags: block-device, network-block-device, nbdev

Currently nbd protocol supports no multiplexing of request bodies. Hence inside a single socket, requests has to be written one after another. The only way to dispatch multiple requests in parallel, is to create more than one socket per nbd client (option `‐connections` or `-C`).

Unfortunately (or I don't know how to configure), I am not able to achieve parallelism more than cpu cores available (`nproc`) even if I use a lot of sockets. Somehow both the `blk-mq` of nbd devices and total simultaneous request submission is upper bounded by the total cpu cores.

I tried changing the `/sys/block/nbd*/queue/nr_requests` value to more than 128, but it is not allowed. I believe `nr_requests` is the maximum number of in-flight requests (submitted but not yet replied by server).

e.g. When I have 8 core cpu, (`nproc = 8`)
All of the following have similar latency results (not IOPS).

```
nbd-client -N default -t 120 -p -R -C 8  localhost 10809 /dev/nbd0
nbd-client -N default -t 120 -p -R -C 12  localhost 10809 /dev/nbd0
nbd-client -N default -t 120 -p -R -C 48  localhost 10809 /dev/nbd0
```

Hence I am limited to submit 8 requests in parallel at a time.
Is there any way to overcome this limitation?

P.S.: This question has nothing to do with IOPS or throughput. The nbd servers capability of fulfilling responses decide that. This is specifically about low latency IO, when a storm of IO requests are coming, it is important for the requests to reach the server in lowest possible time.